# Can I pass an argument to ajax in jqModal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqmodal

I'm using jQuery Modal.
I have two windows that are almost identical, just with a slightly different database query, so I want to repeat as little code as possible.

I was thinking the best way would be to pass an argument somehow to the ajax method so I can return different data based on it but leave everything else the same. I don't see a way to do that..

```
$('#browseVideoWindow').jqm({
    modal: false, 
    trigger: '#videoPersonalLibBtn, #videoVidLibBtn',
    ajax: 'byob/components/videoBrowser.php', //pass a variable based on which the trigger is?
    onLoad: function(event) {
        $("#browseVideoWindow .dialogok").click(function(event) {
            $('#browseVideoWindow').jqmHide();
            changeVideo($('#videoBrowserSel').val());
            });
        }
    });
```

is there a way to facilitate this type of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the trigger type to the query string and process it on the server:

```
$('#browseVideoWindow').jqm({     
modal: false,      
trigger: '#videoPersonalLibBtn, #videoVidLibBtn',
ajax: '@ajax-data'
});
```

...

```
<input type="button" id="videoPersonalLibBtn" ajax-data="byob/components/videoBrowser.php?videoPersonalLibBtn" value="Button 1"/>
<input type="button" id="videoVidLibBtn" ajax-data="byob/components/videoBrowser.php?videoVidLibBtn" value="Button 2"/>
```